# Protractor, Failed: unknown error: cannot focus element on custom input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, protractor

Jumped on the testing wagon and now implementing some E2E tests of a website, but I have run into a troublesome little issue.

I'm trying to select a field then send keys to that input field to change the value, the only problem is the Failed: unknown error: cannot focus element error I can't seem to get past. I have it working on other fields, just not ones with this setup.

pageObject file.

```
var profilePage = function() {

this.firstName = element(by.id('firstname')); 
this.lastName = element(by.id('lastname'));
this.saveBtn = element(by.css('ng-click="saveLocalAccount()"'));
this.cancelBtn = element(by.css('ng-click="cancelChanges()"'));

this.changeName = function(firstname, lastname) {

    this.firstName.click();

    var input = firstName.element(by.css('input'));
    input.click();
    this.input.sendKeys(firstname);

    this.lastName.click();
    this.lastName.sendKeys(lastname);
    browser.waitForAngular();
}
};

module.exports = new profilePage();
```

The spec.

```
var profilePage = require('TestProtractor/E2E/PageObjects/profile.pageObject.js');

describe('Testing the profile page functionality', function() {

var firstNameTest = "firstTest";
var lastNameTest = "lastTest";

it('Navigate to profile page.' ,function() {
    browser.get('xxx');

    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl())
        .toContain('xxx');
}); 

it('Should change the firstname and lastname successfully', function() {
    profilePage.changeName(firstNameTest, lastNameTest);
    expect(element(by.id('firstname')).getText()).toContain(firstNameTest);     
    expect(element(by.id('lastname')).getText()).toContain(firstNameTest);
});
```

});

html

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will see `Failed: unknown error: cannot focus element error` when you are trying to `sendKeys()` to an element which is not an `input`

In your re-usable method `changeName()` you are trying to `sendKeys()` into `lastName = element(by.id('lastname'))` which is not an `input` element. You have to approach it in the same way as you were entering text for first name

Assuming their is an `input` inside lastname too

```
this.changeName = function(firstname, lastname) {

    this.firstName.click();

    var input = firstName.element(by.css('input'));
    input.click();
    this.input.sendKeys(firstname);

    this.lastName.click();
    var input2 = lastName.element(by.css('input'));
    input2.click();
    this.input2.sendKeys(lastName);
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured this one out:

```
var input = firstName.element(by.css('input')); //declare the input
browser.actions().click(input).sendKeys("owiejf").perform(); //sendkeys
```

where browser is the name that's declared here

```
import { browser, element, by, ElementFinder } from 'protractor';
```